# Can lazy loading be considered an example of RAII?

Tags: c++, objective-c, lazy-loading, raii, meta

I have been catching up on my c++ lately, after a couple years of exclusive Objective-C on iOS, and the topic that comes up most on 'new style' c++ is RAII

To make sure I understand RAII concept correctly, would you consider Objective-C lazy loading property accessors a type of RAII? For example, check the following access method

```
- (NSArray *)items {
    if(_items==nil) {
        _items=[[NSArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
    }
    return _items
}
```

Would this be considered an example of RAII? If not, can you please explain where I'm mistaken?

Comment: Why do you think lazy loading would be an element of RAII?

Comment: I am guessing because I apparently do not understand RAII too well :)

Comment: It's a totally legit question, I'm just saying to make the question a bit more helpful to everyone, include the reasoning going through your head. As-is the question is something like, "Is grapefruit an element of climate change?" It would help to explain what you think the connection is.

Comment: well, I thought that RAII is mostly about making sure that the resource is ready to use once you 'get' it, which lazy loading is sorta, maybe similar? But know I know RAII is not the same, and I was mistaken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**RAII** is unfortunately widely misused.

The initial concept *Resources Acquisition Is Initialization* was all about using constructors to guarantee that thing occurred. In this idea:

```
std::fstream out("somefile.txt", "w");
```

should guarantee that if `out` is ever created, then the file exists and is ready to be used.

Therefore, *Lazy Loading is the opposite of RAII* !

Note: nowadays, though, RAII is mostly used to refer to *automatic cleanup*. An example is smart pointers. It's a bit far from its initial goal.

---

Regarding cleanup, another idiom is SBRM for *Scoped Bound Resources Management*. It does not fully capture the idea of deterministic cleanup though. The idea of SBRM is that you guarantee that a resource will be cleaned when a certain object goes out of scope. This can be achieved through `boost::scoped_ptr` for example.

However this fails to capture what a `unique_ptr` does, since you can actually `return` a `unique_ptr` thus letting the resource escape the scope it was created in!

Comment: *Lazy Loading is the opposite of RAII !* This is not true. To the caller, RAII objects can lazy load all day long and the caller doesn't need to be aware. In your example, I don't think RAII implies that the file is created immediately. It only means that the object can't exist without being *conceptually* created and initialized. So it basically forbids methods like `Init` or `Load` or `Create`. In other words, saying they're opposites gives them a relationship that doesn't exist. There are cases where they conflict but in general they are simply unrelated concepts.

Comment: @tenfour: I agree that lazy loading could potentially makes this transparent to the user, however if lazy loading fails how do you handle it ? The user is certain of having the resource and you failed to acquire it ! For a striking example, think of a mutex-lock. With RAII, building the lock object guarantees that I locked the mutex, so I can safely go ahead and do my stuff. Now suppose you decide to lazy load, I acquire the lock on the mutex, do some irrevocable stuff, and use the "locked" item which triggers the lazy load of the lock... and an exception is generated. Oups ?

Comment: It might depend how liberally you apply the term "resource". But if the constructor doesn't *actually* acquire the open file descriptor, then like Matthieu says, resource acquisition *isn't* initialization, resource acquisition is something that can happen any time later (and hence anything later can fail due to failed resource acquisition). What tenfour calls "conceptually creating the file" could be described, "establishing a simple class invariant" (perhaps: that it knows what filename it refers to). It might acquire *a* resource (eg copy the name), but not *the* resource.

Comment: ... so I think Matthieu is right, lazily opening the file is an abuse of the original meaning of the term as he describes it. It's not at all an abuse of the current meaning of the term, but only because the new meaning doesn't demand that there should be any relation at all between resource acquisition and initialization. The current meaning of RAII instead demands that resource release is destruction. It's completely irrelevant when the resource is acquired provided that the object "owns" it once it is.

Comment: Good points, and that makes this question all the more interesting.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Thanks for explaining better than I did :)

Comment: @tenfour: I guess we would really need an acronym/idiom name that specifically ties destruction and release of a resource. It's pervasive in C++ nowadays, and something I really miss in other languages.

Comment: @Matthieu: Python "with" blocks provide an SBRM idiom for users, except that the object still exists afterwards, and the caller might still have a reference to it. So the programmer still has the opportunity to ruin their own day, but if you use it "correctly" you're OK. Java now has a similar mechanism "try with resources" statements. So the rest of the world is getting there :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: well, there is some difference between making it a contract on the type and making it a specific statement. You can forget to use the statement.

Comment: Sure, and with those Java and Python constructs you can remember to use them but still access the object after it has released its resources. It's only part of what you get in C++. I guess it's a question of what you miss -- the ability to lexically scope resources or the inability to screw it up. C++ provides so many other opportunities to screw stuff up that I'd be hard-pressed to say that what I really like about C++ is its imperviousness to programmer error ;-)

Comment: Thank you all for a very detailed conversation. I have learnt a lot from it :)

Comment: @SteveJessop: real programmers don't fear undefined behavior! :/

Answer (score 3):

While the acronym names initialization, the focus of the idiom is destruction. *Resource Acquisition Is Initialization* is more about *Scoped Bound Resource Management*, that is having the object manage the resource and clear it when it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

No, not at all. Also, by "new-style C++" you mean "Everybody sane has been doing this exclusively for the last fifteen years at least".

RAII involves objects of automatic storage duration cleaning up dynamic objects in their destructor, which they own. The exact timing of the ownership is irrelevant.

Comment: I guess I am more out-dated than I thought then :)

Answer (score 0):

No; RAII is where some object that has dynamic storage is wrapped in an object(s) with automatic storage, and is destroyed when the object(s) with automatic storage is/are destroyed.

Lazy loading (loading an object only if and when you really need it, and not before) and RAII are not really related.